# Print a table from an html page

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have a html page, from which a table needs to be sent to a printer. I am using window.print right now.. but that prints the whole page... while I need to print just the table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. You can use [media types print](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html)  ([here is tips](https://css-tricks.com/css-tricks-finally-gets-a-print-stylesheet/), how print html page using stylesheets).
2. You can realize that through popup window - in this window show only table and send it to printer.

Simple example

```
<script>
    function printDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('areaToPrint');
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: The example does not open a new window... does nothing. Any hints?

Comment: 1. Do you have div with id areaToPrint ?
2. In previous code i had small syntax error - getEElement.

Now i check example - all works.

Comment: outerHTML has known issue with firefox and chrome... but the issue is resolvable. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to close the document after finishing writing: `newWin.document.close();`

Comment: I tried this but I need to include the link for the CSS stylesheet for me to get the desired print output. How do I do that?

Comment: You should add newWin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_your_css_file">')

Answer (score 11):

You can give style `display:none` to all unwanted portions of the page. In that way you can print only table.

for ex:

```
<style>
    @media only print {
        footer, header, .sidebar {
            display:none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Very creative way to do it! +1