# jquery hide and show for printing

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

Is it possible to set different properties for jquery show and hide for different media(ex print and screen)?

Lets say I have 2 divs and one button that shows and hides one div and show another. But when I hit print, I would like to show both of them. Despite that if I define in css for printing that it is display:inline; block that is currently hidden is hidden in the print.
How can I resolve this?
Thank you
Dorijan

here is the sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
@media print{
    #div1{
        display:block;
    }

    #div2{
        display:block;
    }
}
</style>

<div id="div1">Div1</div>
<div id="div2">Div2</div>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#div1').hide();$('#div2').show();">Showdiv1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#div2').hide();$('#div1').show();">Showdiv1</a>
```

Comment: Print style support varies cross-browser. Which browser is this? Generally the best way to print content which is different from the screen is via a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your visible element e.g. `.visible`. Than do something like this:

```
@media print {
    .visible {display:block}
}
```

**Update**

After your updated question I would say you need to use the `!important`-declaration...

```
@media print{
    #div1, #div2{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

---

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u2r7R/show)** just hide one div and try to print!

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to include code sample, so I wanted to show both divs when I hit print...

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088890/print-a-table-from-an-html-page/10088956#10088956)  topic, how print table (div etc) from html page.
I think its better solution

Comment: Thank you, my mistake, I forgot to include code sample, so I wanted to show both divs when I hit print...